# No more reps for editing posts after 2000 reps?

Tags: support, reputation

Before reaching 2000 reps, I was awarded +2 reps for every successful (approved) edit. Now, having crossed the 2K limit the system allows me to edit questions and answers without requiring the review and approval cycle.
I have noticed that I'm not getting those +2 reps for the edits that I'm making now.  Is this how the system is or am I missing something?

Not that I'm desperate for reps - I just want to reason this out!

Comment: You only get reputation for the first I believe 500 edits anyways.  You can't get unlimited reputation from edits, that would obviously be an exploit, users with low reputation could exploit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, once you hit 2K, all edits you make are applied immediately. It wouldn't make sense to let people just create infinite rep by making thousands of unilateral edits. You can still make suggested edits to tag wikis (and earn the +2 for them); that will go on until you're 20K.

Look on the bright side - the system now trusts you to supervise *other people's* suggested edits. You are also now entitled to help with tag cleanups, make large question-saving edits, and make little improvements that don't make sense for sub-2Ks to do. Congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

#### Is this how the system is or am I missing something?

It's how the reputation system is designed to work:

> You gain reputation when:
>
> ...
>
> suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)

Source [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation)

And:

> Privilege type: Moderation privilege
>
> Awarded at: 2,000 reputation
>
> ...
>
> That means once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to
>   edit anything in the system without it going through peer review.

Source [edit questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/edit)